# Formgroup controls validation in angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have an address model

```
export class IClientAddress {

    flatNo: string;
    street: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    country: string;
}
```

I use angular reactive forms to build my form so here is the code for that part

```
this.clientForm = this.fb.group({

      clientName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      vatId: [''],
      website: [''],
      phone: [''],
      billingAddress: this.fb.group(new IClientAddress()),
      shippingAddress: this.fb.group(new IClientAddress()),
      clientContacts: this.fb.array([this.fb.group(new IClientContacts())])

    });
```

So Instead of creating new form controls for each I have created a new formgroup with the class(IClientAddress) which has all my controls for the address group.Now I need to validate only some controls inside that IClientAddress class how to do that ? Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Full disclaimer: I haven't used classes to define formgroups. As such, you might have to tweak my answer a bit. I would normally wait for someone more knowledgeable to post, but since this has been sitting for over a month I figured I'd take a whack at it.

If you just need to check if all controls are valid, **angular will do this by default**. That is, a formGroup will only be valid if all of its fields are valid. The trickier part is when the fields interact. In that case, you need to write a custom validator for your formGroup.

Basically, you can pass a validator to not only individual formcontrols, but the form group as a whole. Angular has an example in [their documentation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)

```
/** A hero's name can't match the hero's alter ego */
export const identityRevealedValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
  const name = control.get('name');
  const alterEgo = control.get('alterEgo');

  return name && alterEgo && name.value === alterEgo.value ? { 'identityRevealed': true } : null;
};
```

You would initialize it like this:

```
    const heroForm = new FormGroup({
  'name': new FormControl(),
  'alterEgo': new FormControl(),
  'power': new FormControl()
}, { validators: identityRevealedValidator });
```

As you can see, they are using the inividual controls to determine errors for the larger formgroup. Say the state field is only applicable if the country name is "USA". you could do something like

```
const countryField = control.get('country')
const stateField = control.get('state')
if (countryField.valid && countryField.value === 'USA') {
   return {'requiredStateIfUsa':true}
}
```

This would enable you to validate conditionally on only some fields.

Again, I'm not an angular expert by any means. I hope this answer leads you in the right direction.

EDIT:

As fate would have it, I had to do this today. You have to disable the formcontrols you aren't using.